# How to receive data in Data through the console - VueJs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a component with a form, I need to review data through the console. How can I do this?

I need to receive external data without the vue taking any action. Simply receive the data and fill in the fields.

I tried this

```
document.getElementsByName("nfe.codigo")[0].value = "000";
```

But the amount is not included in the form Data

```
export default {
    name: 'Create',
    data () {
        return {
               nome: ''
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain more what you're trying to do?

Comment: I have an app in vuejs, but I need to inject data into an app form using the console.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted out.

Just access $ vm on the console.